# Dovecot does not delete mails

Tags: email, debian, postfix-mta, dovecot

I installed dovecot on Debian 9 server and everything works fine. But when I delete mails in my mail client and even delete the trash folder, the size of the files does not change. When sending/receiving new mails the dovecot.index.cache file gets bigger

Is that correct? Why is there no change in the file size when deleting mails?

```
drwx------ 2 vmail vmail  40K Mar  7 16:45 cur
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail 7.2K Mar  7 16:41 dovecot.index
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail 363K Mar  7 16:51 dovecot.index.cache
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail 3.9K Mar  7 16:45 dovecot.index.log
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  58K Mar  7 16:41 dovecot.index.log.2
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail   46 Mar  5 08:33 dovecot-keywords
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail   96 Mar  4 12:23 dovecot.mailbox.log
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  15K Mar  7 16:45 dovecot-uidlist
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail    8 Mar  4 12:23 dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--r--r-- 1 vmail vmail    0 Mar  4 12:23 dovecot-uidvalidity.5c7d18c9
drwx------ 5 vmail vmail 4.0K Mar  7 11:52 Drafts
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  157 Mar  7 16:46 maildirsize
drwx------ 2 vmail vmail 4.0K Mar  7 16:45 new
drwx------ 5 vmail vmail 4.0K Mar  7 11:53 Sent
drwx------ 5 vmail vmail 4.0K Mar  5 14:39 Spam
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail   23 Mar  4 12:23 subscriptions
drwx------ 2 vmail vmail 4.0K Mar  7 16:45 tmp
drwx------ 5 vmail vmail 4.0K Mar  7 16:46 Trash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your doevecot seems to use [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) to store IMAP folder mail messages.
   [Dovecot can use a few different storage methods]
   In case of [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir): Check files in `cur` and `new` subfolders. There should be one file per message.
2. `IMAP` protocol may mark messages as deleted without removing them "at once" from disk.
   Inspect messages' single letter flags after `,` in message file name. Search for `T` (Trashed) flag   e.g. `cur/897979431.meteor.42:2,FST`.
   "Marking & removing" may be controlled by "expunge" options in email/IMAP client configuration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir

> The specification defines flags which show whether the message has been read, deleted and so on: the initial (capital) letter of Passed, Replied, Seen, Trashed, Draft, and Flagged.[7]

Comment: Yes, there is one file in cur folder. Anyway: When storing 100 mails in this mailbox the storage increases, but when I delete these 100 mails the storage does not decrease. Even though there is only one file (one message) in cur folder